# Updating domain password on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, passwords, osx-mountain-lion, windows-domain

I'm using Mac OS X on a (windows) domain account. The password is cached on the computer, but I changed the domain password and the account password on the computer will not change. I tried `passwd` at the command line, but I got a `general failure`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a green dot beside your domain name under Users and Groups, in System Preferences?  If not, your computer isn't seeing the domain controller and won't pick up the change.  If so, you may need to talk to your system administrators, because passwords must not be pushing for some reason.

Comment: I have a green dot in the Users/Groups preferences dialogue, but I have a red dot when I try to log in.

Comment: This might help; although it is for OSX password server, not AD.  http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3117  If you see something similar in the plist file that is mentioned there, try following those instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It won't connect using your Wifi credentials at the Login Window. You'll need to plug in an Ethernet cable to get the green dot.

Comment: But eventually figured out the correct credentials with wifi.